# What is difference between session scope and global session scope in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, scope

I am developing my first Spring Boot Application and i think i forgot to add scope thing to my project.
I have Spring Web,Spring Security, Spring Data, Thymeleaf in my project.

When a user login to application it starts with his properties, but when another user login, both users starts to see last user's properties.

I want that all users have their own properties and work concurantly.

Which scope is right for my case?

Do i need to add @Scope annotation to all methods or is there something i can basicly set in application.properties?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
    @RequestMapping(value="/",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView model){

```
    String bagliKullaniciAdi=bagliKullaniciAdiniAl();
    initializeFolders(bagliKullaniciAdi);

    KullaniciEntity kullanici = userServ.findByUsername(bagliKullaniciAdi);

    String ad= kullanici.getAd();
    String soyad = kullanici.getSoyad();

    String tamAd=ad+" "+soyad;

    model.setViewName("index");
    model.addObject("isim", tamAd);

    //initialize
    setCtrlKuyruk(true);
    setAjxEvrakTur("");
    setAjxKategori("");
    setAjxBelgeTur("");
    setAjxFirma("");
    setAjxProje("");
    setAjxAciklama("");

    setAraEvrak("");
    setAraKategori("");
    setAraKelime("");
    setAraFirma("");
    setAraAciklama("");


    return model;
}


public String bagliKullaniciAdiniAl(){

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();               
    String username=auth.getName();

    return username;

}


public Boolean initializeFolders(String bagliKullaniciAdi){

    if("user1".equals(bagliKullaniciAdi)){
        setInitKlasor("/user1/");
        setInitYol("\\\\as04\\ARSIV\\user1\\");
        setInitBelgeAdi(null);
        setInitBelgeSayisi(null);
        setInitTxt(null);
        return true;
    }else if("user2".equals(bagliKullaniciAdi)){
        setInitKlasor("/user2/");
        setInitYol("\\\\as04\\ARSIV\\user2\\");
        setInitBelgeAdi(null);
        setInitBelgeSayisi(null);
        setInitTxt(null);
        return true;
    }else if..... many users
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The @scope declaration only applied to servlet request endpoints. When working with properties, I assume your using java.util.Properties, you need to define one Properties per user and use the basic Java code to ensure thread safety. If each user session has it own properties then there is no problems there. Hope this helps

Comment: i think used wrong word with propety. i mean properties of classes which has getter and setter methods. And my application running on Tomcat 9.

Comment: By default, request scope is used if no scope declaration. As long as you not declaring the class as static, all the classes initialised by the request should be bounded to that request only.

Comment: There is only one static class which is main class. In my controller users properties(variables which has getter and setter functions) are being initialized accordingly logged in user. But when more than one user logged in all users start to have last users properties. How can i set application for all users have their own properties?

Comment: Post some example code to get better understanding. Your using folders which I assume it is filesystem related? I assume every user has it own home directory? If so, there shouldn't be a problem there.

Comment: codes are added to topic. Folders are filesystem related home directories. When user logged in, they are redirected to home page and at the controller variables are being initialized accordingly logged in user. the problem is that when there are more than one user logged in to application, all users started to use last users inital values.

Comment: I think the problem is in the method "public String bagliKullaniciAdiniAl()". You need to ensure its returning the correct user on every login. I would suggest to debug or add logging to ensure every logins are unique. The rest of the code looks correct.

Comment: i checked it and that method returns logged in username correctly.

Comment: The problem is solved when i added @Scope("session") to the controller. Thanks for your help anyway.